# Уточнение, пояснение и сопутствующее обособление

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Я видел многих воинов, **героев войны в прошлом**, которые не могли больше сражаться.

Это уточняющий или пояснительный член предложения? Как их различить?

Можно ли выделить это определение тире? В каком случае?

Comment: _Я видел многих воинов, героев войны в прошлом, которые не могли больше сражаться._ === Мягко говоря, очень _"странная"_ фраза. Никакие знаки препинания её не спасут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)Это тема **обособления приложений**.

2) Распространенное приложение после определяемого слова практически всегда обособляется, исключением является вариант **нарицательного сущ. перед собственным сущ.** при отсутствии **обстоятельственного или уточняющего значения**, например:
Артиллерист береговой охраны Николаев очень хорошо знал побережье. Дочь Дарьи Михайловны Наталья Алексеевна с первого взгляда могла не понравиться.

Сравнить: **Артиллерист береговой охраны**, Николаев очень хорошо знал побережье (значение причины). Дочь Дарьи Михайловны, **Наталья Алексеевна**, с первого взгляда могла не понравиться (уточнение).

3) **Авторское решение при выборе тире.**

На  выбор тире при обособлении приложений влияют такие  факторы  как добавочный характер значения и распространенность. Лёгкие судороги – **признак сильного волнения** – пробежали по его щекам (добавочное значение). Рязанцев и Зоя – **его жена** – были из одного класса (уточнение, добавочное значение). Рыбак – **типичный севастопольский старик с худым от ветра лицом** –  сидел на земле и латал рваную сеть (распространенность).

4) В нашем случае **два нариц. сущ**, поэтому приложение **обособляется в обязательном порядке.** Добавочного значения нет, поэтому обособляем запятыми.